# Access Apache site without domain name via IP address on server with multiple virtualhosts

Tags: 14.04, apache2, dns, routing, virtualhost

I have a single Digital Ocean droplet with 5 websites hosted on it via virtualhost. Everything works fine. Their domain names point to each one individually. Using Apache with Ubuntu 14.04.

I want to add a sixth "test" site, without a domain name pointing to it. I want to use it to test out some WordPress stuff. The physical location of the home page to this site is:

/var/www/test_site/html/index.html

Let's say my server's IP address is 555.555.555.555

What do I need to do to make this home page available to anyone on the internet as follows?

555.555.555.555/test_site/html/index.html